# instanceof yields inconsistent results for detecting interfaces?

Tags: java, instanceof

Is there anything tricky I should know about `instanceof`? I'm passing a list of objects through a few methods and testing whether these objects implement a particular interface using `instanceof`. In some cases, `instanceof` correctly identifies objects as implementing the interface, in other cases it doesn't. It appears to be giving me inconsistent results on the same object in different places. Is there any trick/gotcha I should be aware of here?

In anticipation of comments you might have:

1) I know `instanceof` is bad form. I'm working with a less-than-perfect object hierarchy that can't be changed, and this is the least bad thing I can think to do.

2) I'm working to create a code example, but I'll need to simplify my code a lot if I'm going to paste in anything useful here. In the meantime, if you've seen this before and can shed some light, please do.

Comment: Any chance of getting a code sample?

Comment: Just a guess, but it's quite possible that simplifying your code to post a sample might expose the problem. instanceof is an operator, so it should always work the same.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that if I simplify my code enough to paste in for all you helpful folks, I'll find the bug and won't need to :)

Comment: Why do you say that using instanceof is bad form?

Answer (score 14):

Are you loading any types dynamically, potentially from different classloaders? The only time I've seen apparently inconsistent results was when I had two lines of code which *look* like they refer to the same type, but which have actually loaded that type from different classloaders.

Comment: Gosh,  I don't _think_ so. The strangeness is popping up when running a simple junit test case. This gives me enough information to assume that I've done something dumb and just need to simplify. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`instanceof` always returns `false` for `null`. It does not compile if it would be impossible for the static type on the left cannot be an instance of the specified type. Other than that, it should work without surprise.

Unlike C++ (and I believe Smalltalk), an object cannot change type at runtime. In C++ the type changes during construction, so that methods cannot be called from a constructor to derived class [subclass] methods.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, problem solved. As usual, the problem was less wierd than I thought. The project I'm working on is in the unfortunate condition of having some duplicate class names. I was creating the class using foo.MyInterface and testing for instance of bar.MyInterface. Thanks for the responses. It really did help me think it through.

Comment: Ironically, I nearly included this possibility in my answer, but for some reason didn't in the end. That'll teach me - next time I'll post all ideas, no matter how silly :)

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, was also my silly mistake!

Answer (score 5):

The only gotcha I know of is that `null` is `instanceof` no type.

Comment: I had an incredible moment of realization here.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have no classloading problem, instanceof works consistently. 
I guess you know A instanceof B returns true if the A is inherited from B, or some of the interfaces A implements or classes A extends, are instanceof B.

If you get false when you expect true, you probably are trying to compare instances comming from different ClassLoaders.

Answer (score 0):

You may be wanting "isAssignable" instead of instanceof:

```
if (MyInterface.isAssignableFrom(myObject.getClass())) {
  //  do work here
}
```

This will return true for classes that implement your interface.

Comment: Exactly the same as instanceof, but throws an NPE if myObject is null.

Comment: ...better to use MyInterface.class.isInstance(myObject) - this doesn't throw an NPE. Even this is pointless if you know MyInterface at compile time - might as well use instanceof