# How to check if object implements particular interface, but not the descendants of this interface, in Java

Tags: java, class, interface, instanceof

I have a tree structure, where some nodes must contain only objects implementing particular interface. But there is interfaces extending that interface, and objects, implementing them, should not be contained in nodes.

So i need to check if object implements strictly particular interface.

```
public interface IProcessCell {...}
public interface IMethodCell extends IProcessCell {...}

IProcessCell processInstance = new IProcessCell() {...}
IMethodCell methodInstance = new IMethodCell() {...}

/** Method implementing desired check */
public boolean check(IProcessCell instance) {...}
```

Method check must return true for processInstance, but false for methodInstance

Comment: Maybe you can provide us with an example with made up names. It would be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  If `Foo` is an interface extending `Bar`, then `Bar` should be usable in every single place a `Foo` should be usable.

Comment: Perhaps the [instanceOf][1] operator might help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631099/instanceof-yields-inconsistent-results-for-detecting-interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29)

but to me the thing you are trying to do is like patching up badly written app. To me, the better way is creating a new interface (which only desired object will implement) and making the "tree structure" nodes require that particular interface.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at my mistake. Creating separate interfaces for nodes appeared to be simple task in my project. How i didn't thought about it before?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of implemented interfaces using [getInterfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29).

Assuming you already casted your instance to the desired interface, you just have to test that `yourInstance.getClass().getInterfaces().length==1`

Answer (score 1):

Class implements the getInterfaces() method. It returns a Class[]. Using this you could iterate and do a comparison until found or not found.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `getClass().getInterfaces()` on the node, then iterate through the returned classes and check how many are assignable from the particular interface you care about.  So if you have:

```
interface A {
}

interface B extends A {
}

class NodeA implements A {
}

class NodeB implements B {
}
```

If you're looking for a node instance that just implements A you should be able to do:

```
new NodeA().getClass().getInterfaces();
new NodeB().getClass().getInterfaces();
```

and in each case check that 1) One of the interfaces is A, and 2) `A.class.isAssignableFrom(interface)` returns false for the other returned interfaces.